# C++ - macro using typeof operator giving error

Tags: c++, macros

I am learning C++(STL) from this topcoder link : https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/power-up-c-with-the-standard-template-library-part-1/
and the author has used macros, which i am learning for the first time.
I am trying to use it in the following way but am getting some errors :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

//Macros

#define tr(container, it)\
    for(typeof(container.begin()) it = container.begin(); it!=container.end(); it++);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set< pair<string, pair< int, vector<int> > > >SS; 
    int total = 0; 
    tr(SS, it) { 
        total += it->second.first; 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

ERROR : On the line using the macro, I am getting an error  -> 'it' was not declared in this scope. Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: Got it, removed the semicolon, thank you very much!!

Comment: Don't use such macro... There are predefined structure in modern C++ that allows you to do the same without having to rely on a home-made macro, see e.g. range-based for loop.

Comment: `typeof` is not standard C++. It is, I believe, gcc extension. In C++11 you can use `auto it`, or even better, range for loop.

Comment: If you're going to use a macro, at least give the macro a meaningful, upper-case name.  Using a two-letter, lowercase name conveys no information to the person reading the code.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, can someone point me to a link for such 'practices' to follow?

Comment: @Incomputable I tried using auto, Linter in Sublime says(Yellow Lint) : 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension. Any comments?

Comment: I think you should forego those macros that the site you linked to says are "useful".  Either the current C++ standard makes using those macros obsolete, or in honesty, those macros cause more trouble for persons who know C++ and know exactly what `for` loops look like.  An experienced C++ person would look at the code, and then have to search in your source file(s) for what that macro means.  There is no need for that if you just wrote the code "long hand" and forego the macro.

Comment: @MohitGarg, it is C++11 core language, everything is correct. In fact, Sublime shouldn't worry about it (may be you can change that somewhere).

Comment: @Incomputable Yup, the program is compiling successfully. Thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That tutorial is meant for competitive programming. IIRC the topcoder competition format encourages you to write hard-to-read code (challenge mode of the algorithm contests),  that is why you can usually find two-letters macros and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your for loop. Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor directives are not part of the actual C++ language, and so doesn't follow all the rules of C++. That includes that they are not terminated by a semicolon.

The semicolon at the end will be included in the macro expansion when you use it. That means the for loop looks like this when expanded:

```
for(typeof(SS.begin()) it = SS.begin(); it!=SS.end(); it++);) { 
    total += it->second.first; 
}
```

The loop body is the empty statement created by that semicolon, and the block enclosed in `{}` is not part of the loop.

---

You should also please try to refrain from using macros. In C++ the need for macros have been greatly reduced. There's really no need for a macro in this situation. Nor a function actually (which is the usual way to replace macros).

In fact, if you have a relatively modern and up-to-date compiler then you can use a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto const& p : SS) {
    total += p.second.first;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why should I not use semicolon at the end.